# nuget pack with -IncludeReferencedProjects flag don't work when NET Framework project has project reference to netstandard project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have 2 libraries:

- first library(`First.csproj`) - netstandard1.3
- second library(`Second.csproj`) - .Net framework 4.6.1

`Second.csproj` has project reference to `First.csproj`.

Compilation into VS2017 working without problems.

After that i want to create nuget package for `Second.csproj` with dependency to `First.csproj`, but command

```
 nuget pack Second.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

Failed with error

```
Error occurred when processing file 'E:\blabla\First.csproj': Unable to find 'bin\Release\First\bin\Release\'. Make sure the project has been built.
  Unable to find 'bin\Release\First\bin\Release\'. Make sure the project has been built.
```

My nuget version is latest: NuGet Version: 4.4.1.4656

How can i correctly pack my .NET Framework 4.6.1 project with adding dependency to netstandard library?

Comment: If you want the first project as a dependency it needs to have a .nuspec file, with the same name as the project.

Comment: i have it. It worked when First.csproj was Net 4.6.1 project. But after change project type to netstandard1.3 it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug of nuget: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4054.

Ugly workaround:

1) Manually add dependency on package of `First.csproj` into `.nuspec` file of `Second.csproj`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency id="First" version="actual version of First here" />
</dependencies>
```

2) Use nuget pack without flag `-IncludeReferencedProjects`